# yii1 Использование библиотеки с неймспейсами в классах без неймспейсов

Tags: yii, namespace, facebook-graph-api

Есть проект на Yii первой версии, без композера.

Я установил композер и сделал в директории protected фреймворка

```
composer require facebook/graph-sdk
```

Структура каталога:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на github https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

Возможно ли задействовать эту библиотеку с неймспейсами в yii1 без неймспейсов и как именно это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, попробуйте нечто подобное, у меня получалось с api Яндекса

В конфиге

```
    'aliases' => [
        //...
        'Facebook' => 'application.vendor.facebook.<путь до Facebook.php>',
    ],
```

Пример вызова:

```
         $api = new \Facebook\BlaBla\BlaBla();
```